# Anything declared in a method of Java is local (except in some special cases), is that right?

Tags: java

```
public class Triangle {
    double area;
    int height;
    int length;
    
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int x = 0;
        Triangle [ ] ta = new Triangle[4];
        
        while ( x < 4 ) {
            ta[x] = new Triangle();
            ta[x].height = (x + 1) * 2;
            ta[x].length = x + 4;
            ta[x].setArea();
            System.out.print("triangle "+x+", area");
            System.out.println(" = " + ta[x].area);
            x = x + 1;
        }
        
        int y = x;
        x = 27;
        Triangle t5 = ta[2];
        ta[2].area = 343;
        System.out.print("y = " + y);
        System.out.println(", t5 area = "+ t5.area);
    }
    
    void setArea() {
        ta[x].area = (height * length) / 2;
    }
}
```

---

```
$javac Triangle.java
Triangle.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
ta[x].area = (height * length) / 2;
^
symbol:   variable ta
location: class Triangle
Triangle.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
ta[x].area = (height * length) / 2;
   ^
symbol:   variable x
location: class Triangle
2 errors
```

Of course I soon find that I need to take "ta[x]." thing off the setArea method, that's clear, but now I'm wondering why I cannot put a previously-declared Triangle array before that area function.
Is it because within the method, all things are local and you can't use variables which aren't declared in that method even if you've already declared them in other parts of code? Thank you guys.

Comment: Yes with no exceptions.

Comment: A [variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) declared inside a method is called a "**local variable**" for a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` `ta` are local variable their scope are limited their respective function outside the scope you can not reference it.

Just pass the reference.

```
public class Triangle {
    double area;
    int height;
    int length;
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int x = 0;
        Triangle [ ] ta = new Triangle[4];
        while ( x < 4 ) {
            ta[x] = new Triangle();
            ta[x].height = (x + 1) * 2;
            ta[x].length = x + 4;
            ta[x].setArea(ta[x]);
            System.out.print("triangle "+x+", area");
            System.out.println(" = " + ta[x].area);
            x = x + 1;
        }
        int y = x;
        x = 27;
        Triangle t5 = ta[2];
        ta[2].area = 343;
        System.out.print("y = " + y);
        System.out.println(", t5 area = "+ t5.area);
    }
    void setArea(Triangle t) {
        t.area = (height * length) / 2;
    }
}
```

`ta,x` variable scope limited to Main() funtion

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code?

Answer (score 1):

The question you have asked is related to the concept of scope of a variable in java.
Any variable declared inside {}, can be accessible inside those{} only. Outside the {},variables are not accessible.
In your code area is instance variable of class Triangle having length and height as instance variables.
So to calculate area you can directly use length and height. like
area=length*height
To calculate the area of perticular object call it through that object or you can pass triangle object as mentioned in previous post posted by  user207421

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code?

Answer (score 1):

You have couple of the problems in the snippet. Let me show you:

- It's better to use immutable objects whenever it's possible. Imagine if someone will use your `Triangle` and forget to invoke `setArea()`;
- One of OOP's principles is encapsulation, so you should avoid access to the class's variables directly (only with getters);
- In general, you should store minimum information. E.g. `setArea()` should be moved directly to the `Triangle` class. Moreover, it's pretty simple to calculate and it's better to do it
- And finally look at *division* operation; before doing `/` you have to cast the result to the `double`. If you do `(int + int) / int` - the result will always be an integer.

Please check my solution:

```java
// class is final (this is not mandatory)
public final class Triangle {

    // variables are final (in general this is good approach)
    // variables are private (access only via getters)
    private final int width;
    private final int height;

    public Triangle(int width, int height) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    // 2.0 is very important, here we cast (width * height) to double before division
    public double getArea() {
        return (width * height) / 2.0;
    }

}
```

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Triangle[] triangles = createTriangles(4);
        print(triangles);
    }

    private static Triangle[] createTriangles(int total) {
        Triangle[] triangles = new Triangle[total];

        // for loops letters like i,j,k are more common (x is mostly to 2D)
        for (int i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++) {
            int width = i + 4;
            int height = (i + 1) * 2;
            triangles[i] = new Triangle(width, height);
        }

        return triangles;
    }

    private static void print(Triangle... triangles) {
        if (triangles != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < triangles.length; i++)
                System.out.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "triangle %d, area = %.2f",
                                                  i, triangles[i].getArea());
    }

}
```

Comment: Casting the result of integer division to `double` is not sufficient. The damage has already been done. You have to cast one of the *operands.* And the 2.0 in your code does not exactly 'cast (width * height) to double'.

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code?

Answer (score 1):

The setArea() mehtod is part of the class triangle,so there is no issue in calculating area of a trisngle.

```
public class Triangle {
double area;
int height;
int length;


public double setArea(){        
    return area=(length*height)/2;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x=0;
    Triangle [ ] ta = new Triangle[4];
    while ( x < 4 ) {
        ta[x] = new Triangle();
        ta[x].height = (x + 1) * 2;
        ta[x].length = x + 4;
        ta[x].setArea();
        System.out.print("triangle "+x+", area");
        System.out.println(" = " + ta[x].area);
        x = x + 1;
    }
    int y = x;
    x = 27;
    Triangle t5 = ta[2];
    ta[2].area = 343;
    System.out.print("y = " + y);
    System.out.println(", t5 area = "+ t5.area);

    
}
```

}